# Variables in double parentheses in YAML file

Tags: yaml

I am working on a pipeline and bumped into YAML file with multiple variables inserted with double parentheses, e.g. ((project_name)). Google surprisingly was not helpful with that. What can it mean/do? Based on studying the repository some of them refer to the global variables in the config directory, some however are nowhere to be found. Thanks for help, I am new to YAML!

Comment: Which application processes the YAML file? `((var))` is not special syntax in YAML, it's just a scalar; the application might post-process this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The YAML is processed by Concourse, a CI/CD tool :).

Comment: So it seems you are searching for [this documentation page](https://concourse-ci.org/vars.html)?